# How do I merge and concatenate the data from each row in two separate source files?

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I have two source files which I need to combine on a row by row basis. I am happy reading the files into a variable and I am happy with the logic but the syntax has me stumped. For each row in file 1 I need to loop round each row in file 2 and output the two variables concatenated together:

File 1:

```
<rows>
    <row>1</row>
    <row>2</row>
    <row>3</row>
    <row>4</row>
</rows>
```

File 2:

```
<rows>
    <row>a</row>
    <row>b</row>
</rows>
```

Required output:

```
<rows>
    <row>1/a</row>
    <row>1/b</row>
    <row>2/a</row>
    <row>2/b</row>
    <row>3/a</row>
    <row>3/b</row>
    <row>4/a</row>
    <row>4/b</row>
<rows>
```

My (poor) attempt at getting the XSLT to work:

```
<rows>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file1.xml')/rows/row" />
</rows>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file2.xml')/rows/row" />
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="row">
    <row><xsl:value-of select="???" />/<xsl:value-of select="???" /></row>
</xsl:template>
```

(These files are simplified versions of what I actually have)

How do I make one template match one 'row' value and the other match another (both source files use the same structure). And how do I set those '???' values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2">
    <rows>
        <row>a</row>
        <row>b</row>
    </rows>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <rows>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </rows>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc2/*/row" mode="doc2">
     <xsl:with-param name="pValue" select="."/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row" mode="doc2">
   <xsl:param name="pValue" />

   <row><xsl:sequence select="concat($pValue, '/', .)"/></row>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided first XML document:**

```
<rows>
    <row>1</row>
    <row>2</row>
    <row>3</row>
    <row>4</row>
</rows>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<rows>
   <row>1/a</row>
   <row>1/b</row>
   <row>2/a</row>
   <row>2/b</row>
   <row>3/a</row>
   <row>3/b</row>
   <row>4/a</row>
   <row>4/b</row>
</rows>
```

Comment: Just so I know HOW this works, could you explain what this section is doing please: `<xsl:template match="node()|@*">...</xsl:template>`

Comment: @TheArtfulBenny: This is the famous *identity rule* -- using and overriding the identity template is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. This make it possible to provide easy, short and simple solutions to tasks such as copying most of the nodes "as-is" and changing, deleting, replacing or adding a few specifc nodes. You can read more on this topic here (recommended): http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html

Comment: @TheArtfulBenny: Yes, it makes things so much easier -- also nicely demonstrates the main architectural ideas of XSLT.